# KendoUI Grid: How to select all pages data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to select data from a kendo grid. I need to select one cell at a time when user clicks one key element in that row. I am successful in getting each row's data from first page but when I go to the next page the same function does not work anymore. Do I have to add code in change function ie., in grid change? 
Here's the code:

```
       $('.data').click(function () {
       alert($(this).text());
       var grid = $("#List").data("kendoGrid");
       var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(this.parentElement.parentElement);
       CData.set('activedata', selectedItem);
        }
```

I understand data source gets all the data but this doesn't work:

```
             $('.data').click(function () {
              alert($(this).text());
              var grid = $("#List").data("kendoGrid");
              var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(this.parentElement.parentElement);
             CData.set('activedata', selectedItem);
              }

              for (var i = 0; i < datasourcedata.length; i++) {
                var currentitem = datasourcedata[i].CompanyID;
                if (currentitem == $('.data')) {
                    selectedItem = grid.dataItem(this.parentElement.parentElement);
                    alert($(selectedItem));
                    Comp.set('activeCompany', selectedItem);
                }
            }
```

Where am I wrong? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**This will help you for printing all pages in kendo grid**

```
var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
dataSource.pageSize(dataSource.total());
```

Answer (score 1):

I change datasource settings.

serverPaging: false, 
serverFiltering: false,
serverSorting: false

solved in this way.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to use jquery events but instead use some kendo approach with [change event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-change). That way you always can change `selectedDataItems` collection based on users actions.

Comment: yes, I figured it out. I was getting entire page worth of data. But if I just select that element and pass it on, it will work.